# Only allow Firebase function to be called by users with specific custom claims

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I've got this function which sets custom claims for a user:

```
export const setUserClaims = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(req.body.uid, req.body.claims);
});
```

I only want this function to be available for users that is a super admin, i.e. custom claims consisting of `{admin: true}`.

So an `admin` can set user claims for support staff for example by calling this function.

I've been searching around but I didn't find an obvious answer to this that is 100% robust and secure.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an HttpsCallable cloud function, that way it will automatically get the authenticated user from the client and put it along with other info into the context.auth object.

The function can be something like this:

```
async function myFunctionImpl(params, context) {

    if (!context.auth.token.admin) {
        throw new HttpsError('permission-denied');
    }
    // function code
}

export const myFunction = functions.https.onCall(myFunctionImpl);
```

To call it you can use the functions client. This is an example for web:

```
await firebase
      .functions()
      .httpsCallable("myFunction")({example: "hello"});
```

That way if you authenticate the user on the client it will pass the authentication to the function.

Comment: Interesting, will try it out.

Comment: It works. Don't forget to properly require `functions.https.HttpsError` otherwise you'll get a `HttpsError is not defined` ;-)